# What are menus called that prevent clicking other places until they are closed?

Tags: window

I am trying to find out how to refer to a particular property of windows I frequently encounter.

These window prevent clicking anywhere else on the computer, and when you try to do so it is often accompanied by the "Windows Background" error sound and/or the menu flashing. An example would be the menu that appears when you are choosing where to save a file to.

I am hoping to find a program that stops Windows from preventing clicking while these menus are open, but I cannot seem to figure out how to refer to these menus in a way a search engine can identify in order to look for a program that would let me do so.

I would appreciate it if anyone knew anything about how to refer to this menu type and would be willing to share.

Comment: It's not a menu, it's a dialog box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such window is called [Modal window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)

Comment: You should have a look at the Windows interface guidelines if you need to know any more terms or operational details of the Windows interface. Here is a starting point to the Windows UI guidelines: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/designprinciples